# Pug interpolation issue of username

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, template-engine

I'm passing the properties of a user to my pug template engine and wanting to print the values of the mongodb user schema out to my edit form. I want them to be the "value" of the input fields unless the user changes it.

In my route, here is the code which generates the edit profile route.

```
User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundUser) {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log("Found user is " + foundUser);
      res.render('editProfile', {currentUser: foundUser});
});
```

In the pug template engine form, I have a field like this:

```
label(for="firstname") First name
input.form-control#firstname(type="text", name='firstname', value="#{currentUser.firstname}")
```

But it's literally placing #{currentUser.firstname} in the input field as the value instead of what is in the database. I've used the #{} syntax before and haven't had an issue. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ES6 template literals for this.

```
input.form-control#firstname(type="text", name='firstname', value=`${currentUser.firstname}`);
```

Those are backticks, not quotes. Just to the left of your 1 key, on your keyboard (if you haven't tried them before, [read this on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)).

Comment: that doesn't seem to work either. Sorry. Just read your second line about the backticks. That does work. Thanks!